# Can you help interpreting my svn diff output?

Tags: unix, svn, output, diff

I am comparing two folders using SVN DIFF (one in branch and one in trunk) ... aim is to determine the list of changes.

I then made some changes to the files in the branch. But the output shows that I have modified them in the trunk.

Why does this happen ?

Is there a better command to obtain the results I am looking for ?

The command that I am using now: 
SVN DIFF --SUMMARIZE (URL of a folder in Trunk) (URL of a folder in Branch)

Comment: Sorry, can you please clarify this, you say above that you made some changes in the trunk but the output shows that you modified them in the trunk. Did you mean to say that you modified them in the branch and then they show as modified in the trunk?

Comment: sorry about that .. I edited it now ... and yes u r right ... I made modifications in the branch but the output shows that I made modifications in the trunk

Comment: I suspect you're misinterpreting the output.  Can you post a small example of what you're seeing?

Comment: I am checking in some changes to the branch and adding some files too. I use svn diff command to compare it with the code in the trunk and list out the changes. I am getting the list of the changes showing me that some files have been modified inside the trunk whereas the same files were modified in the branch and not the trunk. 

URL for the trunk(considered as the old URL):
http: //sourcecode.com/test/trunk/TEST/deployer

URL for the branch(considered as the new URL): http: //sourcecode.com/test/branches/TEST_PROJ_DEV/deployer

Comment: So when I use the command svn diff with the --summarize flag as follows:
svn diff --summarize http://sourcecode.com/test/trunk/TEST/deployer http://sourcecode.com/test/branches/TEST_PROJ_DEV/deployer

Expected output :
A      http: //sourcecode.com/test/branches/TEST_PROJ_DEV/deployer/deployer/start_app.sh
M      http: //sourcecode.com/test/branches/TEST_PROJ_DEV/deployer/stop_app.sh

Actual output:
A      http: //sourcecode.com/test/trunk/TEST/deployer/deployer/start_app.sh
M      http: //sourcecode.com/test/trunk/TEST/deployer/stop_app.sh

What should I do to get the output as expected ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Subversion diff --summarize only shows old paths](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/637036/subversion-diff-summarize-only-shows-old-paths)