# Can we find a physical location of a file in the repository?

Tags: unix, svn, location, repository

Is it possible to find the unix location of a file/folder which is in the trunk/branch of the repository ?

Comment: SVN doesn't store the full latest version of every file, only diffs.  And these diffs are spread across many files and compressed.  The work required to reconstruct a file from the repository's file structure is huge.  This sounds like [you are asking the wrong question](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/03/23/558887.aspx) and we need help understanding your problem.

Comment: That's all I needed to know :) thank u so much ... if u have time could u please also address my other question

Comment: This is the link to my other question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26514373/can-you-help-interpreting-my-svn-diff-output

Comment: What do you even mean by "the unix location" of a file in SVN? And why do you need this information?

Comment: I am trying to package only the differences after every build and deploy only the changes to the server ...

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to find the repository location of a file in your working copy, just use `svn info`:

```
 > svn info PlatformAssemblyInfo.cs
Path: PlatformAssemblyInfo.cs
Name: PlatformAssemblyInfo.cs
Working Copy Root Path: C:\Source\Dev
URL: http://your.server.com/Dev/PlatformAssemblyInfo.cs
Relative URL: ^/Dev/PlatformAssemblyInfo.cs
Repository Root: http://your.server.com
Repository UUID: 7b00d45c-cf9c-8245-9a89-7371c32c17a8
Revision: 12345
Node Kind: file
Schedule: normal
Last Changed Author: xxx
Last Changed Rev: 12345
Last Changed Date: 2014-09-16 11:03:36 -0400 (Tue, 16 Sep 2014)
Text Last Updated: 2014-10-07 11:32:19 -0400 (Tue, 07 Oct 2014)
Checksum: 63c6e386936f977959d5e6b758e769f15e9adc49
```

The URL field has the location.  Xml may be easier to parse, and this option supports that as well.

Comment: I just tried svn info on the URL that I am interested in ... doens't give me the "Relative URL" field :( 
looks like that's what I may need