# Unexpected output for svn diff summarize

Tags: svn

I am checking in some changes to the branch and adding some files too. I use svn diff command to compare it with the code in the trunk and list out the changes. I am getting the list of the changes showing me that some files have been modified inside the trunk whereas the same files were modified in the branch and not the trunk.

URL for the trunk(considered as the old URL):
http: //sourcecode.com/test/trunk/TEST/deployer

URL for the branch(considered as the new URL): http: //sourcecode.com/test/branches/TEST_PROJ_DEV/deployer

So when I use the command svn diff with the --summarize flag as follows:

```
svn diff --summarize http://sourcecode.com/test/trunk/TEST/deployer http://sourcecode.com/test/branches/TEST_PROJ_DEV/deployer
```

Expected output :

```
A      http: //sourcecode.com/test/branches/TEST_PROJ_DEV/deployer/deployer/start_app.sh
M      http: //sourcecode.com/test/branches/TEST_PROJ_DEV/deployer/stop_app.sh
```

Actual output:

```
A      http: //sourcecode.com/test/trunk/TEST/deployer/deployer/start_app.sh
M      http: //sourcecode.com/test/trunk/TEST/deployer/stop_app.sh
```

What should I do to get the output as expected ?

Comment: Suspiciously familiar but better posed than [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26514373/1698557)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Subversion diff --summarize only shows old paths](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/637036/subversion-diff-summarize-only-shows-old-paths)

Comment: lol..that was a friend of mine whom I asked a same question. I think he posted it here.